# Laravel How to do this relationship query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, eloquent

I have a current database setup like so :
[image]

I have a user model/vote model/group model/vote subitem model.
There is a many to many relationship between user and vote, and also a many to many relationship between user and subitem.

I want to get a**ll the votes with created at timestamp to something , which belong to a set of group ids , where a particular user does NOT have an entry in user_vote_casts table**.

How can I do this in laravel ?

In mysql, this is what I think is right:

```
SELECT * from vote left join user_vote_casts on vote.id = user_vote_casts.vote_id where user_vote_casts.user_id IS NULL AND vote.id IN (12,3142,512,51,12,1) ;
```

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: see the edit please

Comment: I highly recommend you to read this post:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships It explains everything you need to know about relationships in Laravel.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel Query as per your SQL query:

```
$users = DB::table('vote')
            ->leftJoin('user_vote_casts', 'vote.id', '=', 'user_vote_casts.vote_id')
            ->select('vote.*')
            ->where('user_vote_casts.user_id','')
            ->whereIN('vote.id',[12,3142,512,51,12,1])
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I finally ended up doing is:

```
    $vote = Vote::leftJoin('user_vote_casts', function ($join) {
                $join->on('vote.id', '=', 'user_vote_casts.vote_id');
            })->whereNull('user_vote_casts.user_id')
->orderBy('vote.updated_at', 'DESC')
->take(30)->get();
```